# Quarkus reactive vs quarkus imperative does it matter?

Tags: java, quarkus, reactive, imperative

Hello I was reading the following article [Quarkus reactive architecture](https://quarkus.io/guides/quarkus-reactive-architecture)

At the start of the article it says

> Quarkus is reactive. It’s even more than this: Quarkus unifies reactive and imperative programming. You don’t even have to choose: you can implement reactive components and imperative components then combine them inside the very same application.

just below the middle the article mentions

> Thanks to hints in your code (such as the @Blocking and @NonBlocking annotations), Quarkus extensions can decide when the application logic is blocking or non-blocking.

My questions is does it matter if i write reactive or imperative? For example

Reactive approach

```java
    @GET
    public Uni<List<Fruit>> get() {
        return sf.withTransaction((s,t) -> s
                .createNamedQuery("Fruits.findAll", Fruit.class)
                .getResultList()
        );
    }
```

Imperative approach

```java
    @GET
    @NonBlocking
    public List<Fruit> get() {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Fruits.findAll", Fruit.class)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

Will both these code snippets run with the same reactive benefits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your second snippet uses classic blocking Hibernate ORM, it will **not** work just like the first snippet (which seemingly uses Hibernate Reactive). It contains a blocking call, so you will block the event loop, which is the worst thing you can do in a non-blocking architecture, as it basically works against all the benefits that a non-blocking architecture can give you (see https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#golden_rule).

If your methods are blocking, which includes calls to other libraries that are blocking, you **must not** pretend that they are `@NonBlocking`. If you remove the `@NonBlocking` annotation, the method call will be offloaded to a thread pool and the event loop stays free to handle other requests. This has some overhead, plus the thread pool is not infinite, but I dare to say that it will work just fine in a vast majority of cases.